# Is there a clean way to log the result of a method in Groovy?

Tags: logging, groovy, annotations, return-value

I often find myself doing something like this in order to log the output of a method call:

```
def someMethod() {
    def retVal = //stuff

    log.debug("The return value is: $retVal")
    retVal
}
```

This seems like a lot of ceremony to just log the return value of the method. I know I can use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to do this sort of thing, but I was hoping to do it with just Groovy.

Groovy has the great `@Memoize` annotation to auto-memoize method calls, so does it have a similar `@LogReturn` sort of annotation to do what I'm after?

Ideally, I would expect something clean, like this:

```
@LogReturn("debug")
def someMethod() {
    // Stuff
}
```

<sub>Note 1: I know I could use meta-programming to wrap the method in another method, but I was hoping to be able to make it more explicit with an annotation</sub>

<sub>Note 2: I'm also open to suggestions for accomplishing this in a different way</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any such annotations that would log return value exists in the groovy core. Having said that, I think it should be possible with some AST transformation. If you follow [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Local+AST+Transformations) document, it does somewhat similar i.e. logs entry and exist to annotated method but does not print the return value.

This [blog](http://www.breskeby.com/2010/06/write-a-custom-caching-ast-transformation-with-groovy/) shows how to the catch the returned value for caching, you can instead use that for logging. I suspect you need to be careful as this assumes last statement to be a return value so if you explicitly return before last statement this might not work. This is just my guess, I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score -2):

You can use log annotation with groovy.

```
   @groovy.util.logging.Log
   class Person {
       def method() {
        ...
        log.fine(runLongDatabaseQuery())
       }
   }   
   new Person().method()
```

The `@Log` family of annotations all take one optional parameter: the name of the log variable. By default the log variable is called 'log', but you can change it to whatever you want.

Trick: you can inject `@groovy.util.logging.Slf4j` and use it as a static final org.slf4j.Logger into your class and initializes it using `@Slf4j` (since groovy 1.8) . Useful for integration with the logback framework.

Comment: This doesn't achieve what I'm after at all. I don't want to have to explicitly log the `return` value of my method, I want it to be done by something else. The goal being to still get the logging, but keep the body of the method "pure"